# Referencing SDL2 in a Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdl-2

The graphics library [Veldrid](https://github.com/mellinoe/veldrid) throws:

```
Could not find or load the native library from any name: [ SDL2.dll ]
```

when I try to run the example from [the tutorial](https://mellinoe.github.io/veldrid-docs/articles/getting-started/getting-started-part1.html) in a new C# Console Application, .NET v4.7.1.

When I try to reference [the SDL2 dll](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php), Visual Studio simply shows "A reference to 'C:\...\SDL2.dll' could not be added"

Do I need any additional wrappers? Veldrid.StartupUtilities is already supposed to be a simple wrapper for SDL2.

Do I need to use a different .NET version?

Comment: I guess you only have to add the Sdl DLL to the output directory, not as a managed reference. Best way to do that is to put the DLL into your project root, and set it to Copy if newer in the build action property.

Comment: @RayKoopa: I was able to do that, but Veldrid still can't find it. Do I need to set other Properties or reference it in another way?

Comment: It's only important to end up in the output folder where the executable is started from. Check if it's there, otherwise I don't know how Veldrid has to be set up in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I right-clicked my project, selected `Add >` `Existing Item`, selected the SDL2.dll supplied with the Veldrid download, clicked `Add >` `As Link`, set its `Property` `OnBuild` to Copy if newer and everything worked.