# How to load DLL for SDL2 in C# ? (Problem with DLLImport)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, sdl, dllimport

Using SDL2 bindings for C# from https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS, loading the `SDL2.dll` and using it throught `SDL2.cs` works perfectly.

But I wanted to use the `SDL2_ttf.cs` bindings and a problem occurred: it couldn't load `SDL2_ttf.dll` while the file exists and is in the same directory as SDL2.dll. Throwing me this error:

> **System.DllNotFoundException**: Unable to load DLL 'SDL2_ttf.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

*(Working on Visual Studio 2019)*

Comment: Usually this means that a dependent dll cannot be loaded

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I read that SDL2_ttf.dll had some dependencies yep. Is there something special to do with them? libfreetype-6.dll and zlib1.dll are two of them at least, which I put in the same directory. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: You need all the dependencies. An often overlooked one is the MSVC runtime.

Comment: You can refer to the advice in [Referencing SDL2 in a Visual Studio C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212298/referencing-sdl2-in-a-visual-studio-c-sharp).